# show all session with diffrent name and one suffix in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session

i want to create a shop site by laravel.

i want to create cart page and cart page showing all product that user want to shop it.
i create a session for every product that user want to shop.

i have some session in laravel like this

```php
$_SESSION[cart_133] = [

'product' => 'test1',
'quantity' => '3',
'price' => '30'

];



$_SESSION[cart_30] = [

'product' => 'test2',
'quantity' => '1',
'price' => '50'

];


$_SESSION[cart_65] = [

'product' => 'test3',
'quantity' => '10',
'price' => '653',

];
```

and i wan to showing them like this

```html
<p>test1</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>30</p>

<hr>

<p>test2</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>50</p>

<hr>


<p>test3</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>653</p>

<hr>
<hr>


<p>all price 733</p>
```

Comment: you have to add relations into your models and then get categories with products

Comment: i recently learn laravel and i dont know how to do that. if you can help me

Comment: _First_: Your controller has `$cats`, but you use `$cat` in your foreach. _Second_: You are grouping products by categories. You instead fetch only categories and loop over them using dynamic property(a.k.a relationship) of products to get all products belonging to that particular category.  _Third_: Refer to the docs https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it Laravel way, you have to [define relations](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships).

**Category Model** (each category might have some products)

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

**Product model** (each product belongs to some category)

```php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Then when you want to get categories with their products, you can use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

**Controller**:

```php
$categories = Category::with('products')->get();
```

**View**:

```html
@foreach ($categories as $cat)
    @foreach ($cat->products as $product)
       <!-- product data -->
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use call all session an use substr function to limit one suffix.

you can use this

```php
$x = [];
foreach(Session::all() as $name => $val){
  if(substr($name , 0 , 5 ) == "cart_"){
     $x[$name] = $val;
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($x;);
```